# What happen to pointer members of a class if I assign a rvalue to an object of that?

Tags: c++, class, pointers

What should I expect for the value of B.a after the line B=B.foo(); ?

I expected B.a=44 but I got B.a=0. Is that make sense?

```
class A {   //here is a class A
   public:
     int *a;  

     A(){ a = new int; *a=22;}

     A foo(){ A anA;        //anA is an object of the class A
              *anA.a=44;
              return anA;
     }

     ~A(){ delete a;}

};

int main(){

     A B;

     B=B.foo();

     //What is the value of B.a at this line of the code
}
```

Comment: Your question to the side, if a class has a destructor, it almost certainly should also have a copy constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: Since what you do lead to *undefined behavior* you could expect *anything*. Including (but not limited to) [nasal demons](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). Most likely you will *only* have crashes. And it doesn't matter if you have rvalues or lvalues.

Comment: To expand on the comment by @NeilButterworth, you should read about [the rules of three, five and zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have not defined a copy constructor/assignment operator for `A` and since the assignment to `B` invokes at least the assignment operator (in this case the default one, generated by the compiler), it simply copies the `a` pointer from the returned 'A' instance, then when that instance is deleted the memory is freed and the `a` member in `B` now points to garbage. If you add a little logging it is easy to see that:

```
#include <cstdio>

class A 
{
public:
    int *a;

    A()
    {
        a = new int;
        printf("A::A(0x%p): a is 0x%p\n", this, a);
        *a = 22;
    }

    A foo()
    {
        A anA;
        *anA.a = 44;
        return anA;
    }

    ~A()
    {
        printf("A::~A(0x%p): a is 0x%p\n", this, a);
        delete a;
    }

};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    A B;
    B = B.foo();
}
```

Output:

[image]

So either implement a proper copy constructor/assignment operator, or make one of them/both deleted to escape copying when using raw pointers. For example, adding `A(const A&) = delete;` and `A& operator=(const A&) = delete;` will make your program not compile, and then you can start to examine how you want to approach the places where copying takes place.

The biggest issue here is the semantics. A possible approach to "make this work" could be:

```
#include <cstdio>

class A 
{
public:
    int *a;

    A()
    {
        a = new int;
        printf("A::A()(0x%p): a is 0x%p\n", this, a);
        *a = 22;
    }

    A(const A& otherA)
    {
        a = new int;
        printf("A::A(const A& otherA)(0x%p): a is 0x%p\n", this, a);
        *a = *otherA.a;
    }

    A& operator=(const A& otherA)
    {
        printf("A::operator=(const A& otherA)(0x%p)\n", this);
        // What are the semantics here? Transfer ownership? Copy Value?
        *a = *otherA.a;
        return *this;
    }
    A foo()
    {
        A anA;
        *anA.a = 44;
        return anA;
    }

    ~A()
    {
        printf("A::~A(0x%p): a is 0x%p\n", this, a);
        delete a;
    }

};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    {
        A B;
        B = B.foo();
        printf("B.a is %d\n", *B.a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But then there is the question - what are the semantics of the copy operation? Transfer the ownership of the pointer? Copy the value? Since the compiler cannot answer any on these, it just copies the members.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  So, class A needs to have both copy constructor and assginment opeator.

Comment: @GultekinYegin I'd still advise against using plain pointers and use smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr`.